# Pi3 onboard wifi disappeared, possible hw failure?

Tags: wifi, wireless, pi-3

The onboard wifi suddenly stopped showing up anywhere on my pi. Tried with openelec and raspbian, made a new install of jessie and the problem is the same.

ip link shows this

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:04:0b:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here is my [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/q6X9BxSW)
There is no wlan in /sys/class/net

I tried updating the firmware, that doesn't helped either.
I modprobed the brcmfmac and now I get a

```
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
```

in ip link.
I am out of ideas for now.

Edit: I just noticed my pi runs very hot with no load.

Edit2: The shiny ic near the sd card is scorching hot.

Comment: Sounds kinda broken somehow...what does `vcgencmd measure_temp` say with no load?

Comment: As soon as I can measure it 40.
1min: 46
2 min: 50
http://imgur.com/Q1zwVV2

Comment: That's totally normal.  It should stay about the same under load unless you've packed the thing in insulation.  Why do you believe it is "very hot"?

Comment: Finally it settles at around 52 degrees. But not the cpu which overheats. Without activity the broadcomm wifi gets so hot within minutes it leaves a burn mark.

Comment: 'Leaves a burn mark' = broken. Nothing on the Pi should *ever* do that under no load. Time to send it back. :P

Comment: Is there anything I can do about it? Reverting the frimware etc. Sending back would cost me almost the same as a new pi :(